# What are the part numbers for these book-like items?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[post of LEGO-like books from Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32828073776.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.1.b0143bfaB96vR7&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.14977.166126.0&scm_id=1007.14977.166126.0&scm-url=1007.14977.166126.0&pvid=c73b76cc-b715-4054-a415-266043cf91fc&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.14977.166126.0,pvid:c73b76cc-b715-4054-a415-266043cf91fc,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%235_668%23808%235965%23203_668%23888%233325%2314_668%232717%237562%23425)

Comment: Have you checked BrickLink already? Quick search for "book" gives you all the LEGO items...

Answer (score 2):

Your post links to a clone brand

The original LEGO parts are

Part # 24324 : [Minifigure, Utensil Book Binding with 2 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24324&idColor=115#T=C&C=115) in Pearl Gold

and the [Book Covers from Nexo Knights](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=book%20cover%20nexo%20knights)